# Sending large batch of emails with a specific email template using REST

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, email, batch

Currently: I have a REST call to SaleForce Marketing Cloud that sends an email with a specific template/definition key and a set of attributes.

This is good for sending an email when triggered by our process.

Need: I need a way to send a mass batch of emails with the same template/definition key to different emails AND receive the message key of each for email. I have the email addresses of the recipients and the attributes that need to be used.

This is to attempt to make a very large scheduled email job run faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Marketing Cloud SOAP API, a similar question was answered here [Sending a batch of emails via Marketing Cloud but triggered in Sales Cloud](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224627/sending-a-batch-of-emails-via-marketing-cloud-but-triggered-in-sales-cloud).

Here is the call to send an triggered send to multiple addresses:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Create</a:Action>
      <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:7e0cca04-57bd-4481-864c-6ea8039d2ea0</a:MessageID>
      <a:ReplyTo>
         <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
      </a:ReplyTo>
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">{{soapEndPoint}}</a:To>
      <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{accessToken}}</fueloauth>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <Options>
        <RequestType>Asynchronous</RequestType>
        <QueuePriority>Medium</QueuePriority>
      </Options>
       <Objects xsi:type="TriggeredSend">
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
            <TriggeredSendDefinition>
               <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
               <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
               <CustomerKey>InsertCustomerKeyHere</CustomerKey>
               <SendWindowOpen>1600</SendWindowOpen>
               <SendWindowClose>1800</SendWindowClose>
               <SendLimit>500</SendLimit>
            </TriggeredSendDefinition>
         <Subscribers>
           <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
           <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
           <SubscriberKey>999991</SubscriberKey>
                <EmailAddress>some1@domain.com</EmailAddress>
                <Attributes>
                    <Name>Fname</Name>
                    <Value>Eliot</Value>
                </Attributes>
         </Subscribers>
           <Subscribers>
           <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
           <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
           <SubscriberKey>999992</SubscriberKey>
                <EmailAddress>some2@domain.com</EmailAddress>
                <Attributes>
                    <Name>Fname</Name>
                    <Value>Sam</Value>
                </Attributes>
         </Subscribers>
             <Subscribers>
           <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
           <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
           <SubscriberKey>9999913</SubscriberKey>
                <EmailAddress>some3@domain.com</EmailAddress>
                <Attributes>
                    <Name>Fname</Name>
                    <Value>Josh</Value>
                </Attributes>
         </Subscribers>       
       </Objects>
      </CreateRequest>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

If you are interested in using the REST API specifically you can use the following endpoint and API:

Endpoint: `https://{{et_subdomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/messaging/v1/email/messages`

API POST:

```
{
    "definitionKey": "tapi-ena-appointment",
    "recipients": [
        {
            "contactKey": "aaron.cates@salesforce.com",
            "to": "aaron.cates@salesforce.com",
            "messageKey": "{{$guid}}",
            "attributes": {
                "FirstName": "Aaron",
                "Doctor": "Smith"
            }
        },
        {
            "contactKey": "aaron.cates@salesforce.com",
            "to": "aaron.cates@salesforce.com",
            "messageKey": "{{$guid}}",
            "attributes": {
                "FirstName": "Billy",
                "Doctor": "McNew"
            }
        }
    ],
    "attributes": {
        "GlobalAttribute1": "value_a",
        "GlobalAttribute2": "value_b"
    }
}
```